# Logo image only displays in Chrome desktop

Tags: css, google-chrome, pseudo-element

Our logo on this site displays normally at top left when viewed in Chrome. Missing in Firefox and Opera. Using inspection tools, the HTML `<img class="brand-logo" alt="Holder's Total Security" src="https://holdersecurity.com/wp-content/themes/holders/images/brand-logo.png">` looks normal in Chrome but is pale in Firefox. Obviously trying to tell me something.

I think this stumps me because the original developer used ::before and ::after pseudo-elements, which I have rarely used.

Site... [example of problem](https://holdersecurity.com/)

Comment: Trying to look but the anchor tag surrounding logo is set as display: none;

Comment: It really looks like an issue with the Twitter Bootstrap classes. I would take a closer look at those.

Comment: I also just noticed the anchor tag `<a href="https://holdersecurity.com/" class="visible-lg visible-md visible-sm hidden-xs">`

...and the CSS for that is complex enough to keep be busy for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

I isolated parts of Bootstrap CSS having to do with "responsive utilities". Then compared them to the classes assigned to the `a` tag (`visible-lg visible-md visible-sm hidden-xs`).

Then I made sure the following was at the bottom of my main stylesheet ...

`.visible-lg .visible-md .visible-sm .hidden-xs {
    display:block!important;
}`

The logo now displays normally, but I'm not sure why this suddenly broke after months of working just fine. Chalk it up to excessive Wordpress complexity.